# Browse .jdb output?

Tags: java, database, jdb, crawler4j

I am running [crawler4j](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/) and the output is to the directory `/frontier/`. The files in this directory are

- 00000000.jdb
- je.info.0
- je.info.lck
- je.lck

the .jdb file is the only one with data the other three files have zero bytes. I am not sure what to do with this data. The java program captures the data I wanted but now I am not sure how to browse the data that i've retrieved. (I'm on a Mac so anything that is cross-platform or for OSX is preferable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the source for crawler4j, and it looks like it is using Berkeley DB. [Please search StackOverflow for details on how to access these files.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=berkeley%20db)